# PyQT Zooming is disrupted by mouseMoveEvent(), why?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, zooming, pyside

This class is my current graphicsview. In it, I present at graphicsscene. This graphicsview is scaled by the zoom functions (which you can see below).

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
ZOOM_FACTOR = 2
MAX_ALLOWED_ZOOM = 4

class MapGraphicsView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(parent.size().width(), parent.size().height())
        self.setAlignment(33)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.max_allowed_zoom = MAX_ALLOWED_ZOOM

    # Signal variables used to notify listeners. Listeners are connected in actions.py
    pressed = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QEvent)
    released = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QEvent)
    moved = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QEvent)

    # Notify listeners when window is clicked
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pressed.emit(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.released.emit(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        #self.moved.emit(event)
        pass

    def zoom_in(self):
        self.scale(ZOOM_FACTOR, ZOOM_FACTOR)

    def zoom_out(self):
        self.scale(1/ZOOM_FACTOR, 1/ZOOM_FACTOR)
```

Really, everything works wonderfully. Well, it does if I remove the mouseMoveEvent, which can be seen in the code below. If I remove the event, everything works exactly as intended: the zoom is perfect and it centers right on top of the cursor.

If I leave the mouseMoveEvent in, even though it only performs one action..

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    #self.moved.emit(event)
    pass
```

.. and that action is pass, the whole zoom functionality changes drastically. Instead of zooming on top of the mouse cursor, it seeems as if there is no zoom anchor, and the zoom target instead follows some entirely other system.

Since the zoom function is crucial in my product, I need to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using your code I cannot repeat your reported behavior because it is not a complete example. It seems alright to me, although you could call the super().methods somewhere in the overriden methods, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just call super before handle the event:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
    # your code goes here
```

it did work for me. Do not forget question yourself if a reimplemented method needs it.